# Having trouble understanding pyOpenGl vertices and edges

Tags: python, 3d, pygame, pyopengl, vertices

So I am trying to learn about very basic level 3D modeling in python however I am struggling to understand how the Vertices and edges are positioned and what the numbers I am passing do. Here is an example:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

"""
- A Cube has 8 Nodes/Verticies
- 12 Lines/connections
- 6 Sides
"""

vertices = (
    (1, -1, -1),
    (1, 1, -1),
    (-1, 1, -1),
    (-1, -1, -1),
    (1, -1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (-1, -1, 1),
    (-1, 1, 1)
)

edges = ( #Contains vertexes/nodes
    (0, 1),
    (0, 3),
    (0, 4),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 3),
    (2, 7),
    (6, 3),
    (6, 4),
    (6, 7),
    (5, 1),
    (5, 4),
    (5, 7)
)


def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_LINES)

    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex]) #Draws vertex's in position given according to vertices array
    glEnd()


def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (800, 600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

    gluPerspective(35, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0) #FOV, aspect ratio. clipping plane

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5) #X,Y,Z -5 to zoom out on z axis
    glRotatef(20, 0, 0, 0) #Degrees, x,y,z

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) #Clears the screen

        Cube()
        pygame.display.flip() #Cant use update
        pygame.time.wait(10)

main()




pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I made this following a great tutorial from sentdex [Open GL and Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D57J48UAQCs). However I am having a hard time understanding why he puts in the numbers he does for the vertices. If anyone could explain the system of numbering that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vertices` is an array of 8 different 3 dimensional [Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system), with the indices from 0 to 7:

```
vertices = (
    ( 1, -1, -1),   # 0
    ( 1,  1, -1),   # 1
    (-1,  1, -1),   # 2
    (-1, -1, -1),   # 3
    ( 1, -1,  1),   # 4
    ( 1,  1,  1),   # 5
    (-1, -1,  1),   # 6
    (-1,  1,  1)    # 7
)
```

The coordinates define the corner points of a cube.

`edges` is an array which defines the edges of the cube. Each pair of indices in the array defines a line from one corner point to another.

e.g. (0, 1) defines an edge from (1, -1, -1) to (1, 1, -1).

The following function takes each pair of indices of the array, reads the 2 coordinates which belong to the indices and draws a line from the first coordinate to the second. For this is used the OpenGL [Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) type `GL_LINE`, which draws a bunch of line segments between 2 consecutive points.

```
def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex]) 
    glEnd()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The wiki link was also very helpful :)